# Sitecore images in the Media Library are not displaying in Page Editor on CM instance, but appear in the Media Library and on CD instance

Tags: sitecore, media, protected, media-library, sitecore-media-library

I have a bizarre issue with one of my Sitecore sites. Most (but not all) of the images in the Media Library are not displaying in Page Editor/CM. When I view my site in Page Editor or go to *mysite.prod-cm.com*, the images just show the broken image icon. If I try to go to the image directly, such as `mysite.prod-cm.com/~/media/Upload/exampleImage.ashx` it returns an error page. However, if I go to the same path on CD, `mysite.com/~/media/Upload/exampleImage.ashx`, the image displays. In Sitecore, in the master database, I see all my images, I am able to preview them and download them and there appears to be nothing wrong with the files.

I checked the logs to see if there were any useful clues about why the image paths are returning an error, and I see the following message

> "WARN  Protected page accessed with no current user".

Is this a security setting in Sitecore? This only started happening recently, is there a way to unprotect the Media Library? Like I said, *some* images still show up, but any new images I add appear broken. The only other message in my logs is

> "WARN  Memory usage exceeded the MemoryMonitor threshold".

To add on, I can view the images by the path with their item ID, such as `mysite.prod-cm.com/~/media/C98B4DAC5FBD416CABF0070D087AE5E2.ashx`. That works, but the path with the item name does not.

Comment: Is the problem only with images in "upload" folder only?

Comment: No, it's across all folders

Comment: What is the example of incorrect media item url?

Comment: Maybe you have a stray security setting on a parent folder (maybe deny for a specific role?). Check with the Access Viewer maybe

Comment: I've got same problem and I solved it by editing Access Viewer on specific role, like jammykam says. And don't forget to publish the site after you change the Access Viewer setting

Comment: I have the exact same problem right now. Did you ever resolve this? I have verified that permissions are not an issue. I can toggle between Edit and Preview in the EE, and I can't see anything in Edit, and the content comes up in Preview, but images are always linked and broken. I have verified my Solr install is up and working now, in case of indexing.  All the symptoms are exactly the same.